# Facebook $signed_request['user_id'] Not Pulling User ID

Tags: php, facebook

I've looked around so if this is a re-post, send me in the right direction but I keep getting 1 single random character when I run this.  What am I doing wrong?  I just want to output the user ID.

```
 <?php require 'facebook.php';
  $facebook = new Facebook( array( 
   'appId'   => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   'secret'  => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   'cookie'  => true
 ) );

 try {
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');
 } catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
  error_log( $e );
  }


 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
 $user_id = $signed_request['user_id'];
 echo $user_id;


 $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
 $liked = $signed_request['page']['liked'];

 ?>
```

Also the $signed_request['page']['liked'] works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that a copy/paste from your code?
If so

```
 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
 $user_id = $signed_request['user_id'];
 echo $user_id;
```

won't work, it's not the correct signed_request and it won't be readable because you haven't  decrypted the response (in the PHP SDK the decryption is automatic in the 'getSignedRequest()' function)

The page code you have is correct, so to get the current user ID, assuming that the user has accepted the auth dialog for your app, the code should be

```
 $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
 $user_id = $signed_request['user_id'];
 echo $user_id
```

Comment: This works in the canvas, I was being stupid and not asking for the permissions with the auth dialog.  Is there a way to use the auth dialog on the page tab?

Comment: Yep, there's an example in the [Authentication in a page tab](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/) docs